# Web scraping, distinguishing between resources and elements or a webpage

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2 
import cookielib


cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.open("*******")



br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['ctl00$BodyContent$Username'] = '****'
br.form['ctl00$BodyContent$Password'] = '****'
br.submit()

print br.response().read()
```

At the moment this scrapes a web page and returns the resources, but not the actual html of the page (content and such). How do I change it so that I can get the html instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your'e close, you should use beautiful soup to get the tags into a nice xml format.

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2 
import cookielib


cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.open("*******")



br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['ctl00$BodyContent$Username'] = '****'
br.form['ctl00$BodyContent$Password'] = '****'
br.submit()

soup =  BeautifulSoup(br.response().read())

print soup
or
for row in soup:
    print row
```

Comment: Although that gives more, it still doesn't give me the data I can see in the html output in web inspector?

Comment: Can you post a small segment of the soup response? or the url and form and I can take a closer look.

Comment: Which bit of the soup response would you like to see? Theres about a thousand lines..

Comment: Which part are you missing?

Comment: Ah, I've just realised it gets the information from other links doesn't have all the information on one html page. Thanks for your help!